# Cannot fetch data from API (null Object) and display on HTML page

Tags: angular, express, rest, http

I am new to Angular and Express. Right now, I am setting up my api endpoints on the server side and I am able to access the data from my db through it.

[Succesfully retrieved the data via postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/644xZ.png)

However, when I tried to access the data from the front-end (basically doing a http call to the endpoint), I received this error.

[GET not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DoXj.png)

You can see that there is an object there since I use {{ data }} (I have tried {{ data || json }}), but I have checked it, it is null.

My goal right now is for the **front-end to fetch the data** and **display it on the html page**.

These are the snippets of my code that I think are relevant to my question.

homepage.component.ts

```
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit{
  public data: any;

  constructor(private httpCall: HttpService){
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.readData();

  }

  readData(){
    this.httpCall.requestCall(AuthEndPoints.READ_USER, ApiMethod.GET)?.subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      console.log(data);
    })
  };
}
```

http.service.ts

```
export class HttpService {
    private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:4200';

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private _error: ErrorService,
    ) {}

    requestCall(api: AuthEndPoints, method: ApiMethod, data?: any){
        let response;

        switch(method){
            case ApiMethod.GET:
                response = this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiUrl}${api}`)
                    .pipe(catchError(async (err) => this.handleError(err)));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return response;
    }

    handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse){
        if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
            return console.error('An error has occured: ', error.error.message);
        }else{
            this._error.whichError(error.status, error.message);
            return throwError({error: error.message, status: error.status});
        }
    }
}
```

const.ts (where i define the authEndPoints etc)

```
export enum AuthEndPoints{
    CREATE_USER = "/users",
    READ_USER = "/homepage/users",
    UPDATE_USER = "/users/:id",
    DELETE_USER = "/users/:id",

    READ_FACILITIES = "/facilities" 
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const user = require('./user-queries');
const app = express(); 

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

var corsDetails = {
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
}

const PORT = 4200;

app.get('/homepage/users', cors(corsDetails), user.getUsers);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

homepage-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage.component'
  
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomepageComponent },
    { path: 'users', component: HomepageComponent}
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class HomeRoutingModule{}
```

Things I have tried:

1. Using a different port for the server and front-end side.
2. Configuring cors.
3. Using a direct url paste into the http call (instead of the custom function I created).
4. Adding 'users' path to my homepage component (mine uses lazy loading).
5. Allowing all access to my server.
6. Using a proxy (no more GET error here but now I cannot see the html page).

Things I haven't tried:

1. Defining the data variable as an array.
2. Deploying my server onto the net instead of using localhost.

I feel quite down, been analyzing the code for a couple days now, reading and trying whatever solution there is. I am not sure where I got it wrong. Do you mind looking through it?

Many thanks, community.

Comment: If I understand correctly what the problem is, it looks like you have an Observable within another one, something like `Observable<Observable<any>>` because where you are console logging, it displays an `Observable` which is not correct because you are already `subscribe`ing to it, I recommend also not using `any`, take the time to explicitly define what response/data types you are using

Comment: it's showing [Object] because that what it is... it's a JS array.  You might type it as a string to display it, but it's not all that useful that way.  (and come to think of it, [object Object] might just be JS's attempt at turning it into a string) You should make the types match backend and front.

Comment: @Andres2142 Yes, I have tried modifying the code based on your suggestions. I got no more Observable showing in my console and the types match but the error remains. My GET fetch still cannot find the URL sadly

Comment: @pcalkins Still doesn't work unfortunately